# Having a strange error when trying to implement a spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in android and while I was doing it I got this strange syntax error and I am unable to resolve it.

The code I was writing :

```
public class AddContact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_number_array);

    //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.phone_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
}
```

While I was writing "Adapter.setDropDownViewResource...." I get this weird error and this is stack trace:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
     EnumHeaderName
    - Syntax error on token "Adapter", delete this token
    - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
```

I can't figure what the problem is. Can someone please help?

Comment: please post complete code and also stack trace. but if this is your complete code you have to finish your last line. which says `Adapter.`

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to finish the line

Comment: @AnmolWadhwa check my answer put your code at right place to run

Comment: You cannot place runnable code in the class body... You should familiarise yourself with some basic Java before you start with Android. That also applies to conventions... Variables should not start with capital letters (e.g. use `adapter` instead of `Adapter`)!

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you so much @Hi-Tech KitKat Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting your code at wrong place you should do spinner work into one of method 
either `onCreate` or `onStart`

Just replace your class code it will work

```
public class AddContact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewMain);   

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Adapter =
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.phone_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of
    // choices appears
    spinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't invoke methods on class level unless you are storing result of that method in field, but are trying to invoke `setDropDownViewResource` method on `Adapter` at class level

```
class AddContact {
    //...
    Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(...);
}
```

Try moving this code to constructor, method, or initialization block.

```
class AddContact {
    //...

    {//initialization block
        Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(...);
    }
    public AddContact (){//constructor
        Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(...);
    }

    void someMethod(){
        Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very confident in implementing spinners, so I am not quite sure as to which method I should put it in.

Comment: @AnmolWadhwa I am not Android developer so can't help you in this matter but other answer seems to contain informations you need. I posted this answer because your problem related only to Java.